# GeoServer Mapbox Vector Tile

Tags: geoserver, mapbox

I have a spring boot application which is making request to GeoServer to get a layer as a vector tile instead of the front end application making the request directly. The problem is I am not getting the response as a .pbf file instead I am getting it as a file. My code is below:

```
#controller

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/tile-layer",produces= {"application/x-protobuf"})
public Object getWmsVectorLayerMap(@RequestParam(name = "SRS", required = true) String crs,
        @RequestParam(name = "LAYERS", required = true) String layers) {
    try {
    //  logger.info("making wms request...");
        String layer = Utilities.getLayers(layers).replace(" ", "%20");
        String url = wmsTileLayerUrl + "layers=" + layer +"&srs=" + crs;
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        String auth = geoServerUsername + ":" + geoServerPassword;
        byte[] authentication = auth.getBytes();
        byte[] base64Authentication = Base64Utils.encode(authentication);
        String baseCredential = new String(base64Authentication);
        header.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + baseCredential);
        header.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
        header.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/x-protobuf"));
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(header);
        //restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class);
        ResponseEntity<Object> rsp = restTemplate.exchange(new URI(url), HttpMethod.GET, request, Object.class);
        return rsp.getBody();       
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        logger.error("Error while making wms request because: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? How do I solve it please?

Comment: is the file an error message?

Comment: no it isnt. apparently i was doing it wrong. i have been able to solve it and it is getting the .pbf file now. The update code is as follow:

Comment: HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(header);
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
   //restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class);
   ResponseEntity<byte[]> rsp = restTemplate.exchange(new URI(url), HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=layervectortile.pbf");
   OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
   output.write(rsp.getBody());
   output.close();
   response.getOutputStream().close();

Comment: I also change the return type to void so im writing the file to the HttpServletResponse object directly

Comment: please make that into an answer and then accept it for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. Apparently I was doing it wrong. I have been able to solve it and it is getting the .pbf file now. The update code is as follows:

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(header); 
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
//restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class); 
ResponseEntity<byte[]> rsp = restTemplate.exchange(new URI(url), HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment;filename=layervectortile.pbf"); 
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
output.write(rsp.getBody()); 
output.close(); 
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

I also changed the return type to void so I'm writing the file to the HttpServletResponse object directly